# How do you install a package binary into a virtual environment

Tags: python, windows, virtualenv

So you can install packages in the form of binaries such as [these](https://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/files/pywin32/Build%20217/). But if you just double click it would presumably install it in the global environment. If you wanted to install it a virtualenv, how would you do it?

Answer (score 0):

Normally you would use [pip](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/) in a virtualenv - most packages can be installed that way and [pypiwin32](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pypiwin32/219) seems to be an alias for pip-installable pywin32 so with pip you would install this.

Comment: Though I would like to install a specific version and it seems like `pypiwin32` starts with version 219 whereas I would want version 217. When I try to install version 217 through `setup.py install` it fails me.